# Tkinter Listbox artifact

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am developing a UI that uses a Tkinter `Listbox` item to display a bunch of dynamically inserted frames that contain other labels. The `Listbox` works, but in turn it is displaying some weird indexes that I do not want to see in the window.
They look like this.
[image]
How can I disable these indexes from showing up?
This is the part of code that is responsible for initialising the `Listbox`

```
vertical_frame = Listbox(root)

vertical_frame.config(bg="#394144", bd=0, highlightthickness=0, height=10, selectmode=0,
                      activestyle="none", fg="#fff", exportselection=0)
```

Also, the frame is used in a function to be able to modify it's contents in a dynamic way.
The only thing I do there is

```
_frame.insert(END, temp_frame)
_frame.pack()
```

where `_frame` stands for `vertical_frame`, but it is passed to a function.
How can I disable the wierd numbers from showing up?

Comment: `Listbox` widgets are for displaying a set of lines of text, not other nested widgets like frames.

Comment: Would you recommend me other manager?

Comment: What I am trying to do eventually is to have a scrollbar to this manager, so  that I will be able to see more entries, but still have my window with a decent resolution.

Comment: You can nest frames in frames, so you could create your own custom `ListBox`-like widget (and even give it scrollbars) if desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "weird indexes" are the string representation of widgets. To get them to not show up, you need to remove the code that is trying to insert a widget into a listbox. The listbox can only display text.

If you are trying to create a scrollable list of frames, you will need to either embed them in a canvas, or embed them in a text widget. Those are the two widgets that both support scrolling and the embedding of other widgets.

Comment: @Justplayit94: To embed a frame (or other) widget onto a canvas, first create a `Canvas` object and then use its `create_window()` method specifying the desired widget as the `window=` keyword argument's value.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it this way.